# Conditional Cumulative

Tags: ms-access

I want to have a running sum in my MS ACCESS report, but with a condition.
The condition is IF (Gap>1,0, Cumulative minutes in Previous Row + Minutes in Current Row)
Is there any way to achieve this? I would appreciate any insights or solutions. Thanks

[image]

Comment: So if Gap >1 or not a number, use 0 for Hour? If this were a cumulative calc, why don't the last three records show 1.08 each? Not understanding the logic.

Comment: Hi @june7
Sorry for the confusion caused.
First Cummulatve is 1, then 1.08, then 2.08
then at the fourth row, you see the GAP>0, so the cumulative goes back to 0.

Comment: So you are showing your attempt, not what you want? Helpful to show desired result.

Comment: Why does Gap show hyphen in some records?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a way to 0 out and restart cumulative without having some way to group records.

Comment: Hi June7, the attached picture is what I did it on excel.

Comment: is there a way to achieve this in any other way?

Comment: Maybe with VBA custom function.

Comment: I am not really familiar with the vba custom function. could you please help..?

Comment: A VBA custom function is a procedure you write in VBA code. You need to learn VBA programming and do this work yourself or contract a professional programmer. Stackoverflow is not intended to be a code writing service. What you want is original coding with parameters specific to your situation and likely to be rather complicated.

Comment: You could make an answer to your question and accept it so maybe someone could benefit from it. I suppose solution simpler than I thought?

Comment: found this one and solved it
https://www.reddit.com/r/MSAccess/comments/i0jx4s/conditional_cummulative/

Comment: Thanks for sharing link but pages can disappear. Still recommend posting answer with your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private lngTotal As Long

Public Function lngConditional_Cummulative(ByVal lngID As Long, _
                                       ByVal lngNumber As Long) As Long

If lngID = 1& Or _
 lngNumber = 0& Then
 lngTotal = 0&
End If ' If lngID = 1& Or lngNumber = 0& Then

lngTotal = lngTotal + lngNumber

lngConditional_Cummulative = lngTotal 

End Function
```

Comment: How did you utilize this procedure - call it from a query or textbox? What fields served as inputs for the arguments? I tried it with your sample data and results are not what you describe as desired. I have never seen this usage of & character. Just posting code without accompanying explanation is discouraged.